# Reshaping pandas dataframe, converting values of an existing column into new lower level columns with index ignored

Tags: python, pandas, reshape, multi-index

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
>>> x[x.site_num<3]
Out[44]: 
       6890011  site_num
item                    
0     3.226545         0
1     3.226698         1
2     3.221418         2
12    3.231642         0
13    3.226331         1
14    3.221449         2
24    3.231123         0
25    3.226454         1
26    3.226240         2
36    3.226484         0
37    3.226240         1
38    3.221571         2
48    3.226118         0
49    3.226331         1
50    3.221021         2
```

and i'm trying to make it look like this:

```
       6890011
             0         1         2           
item
0     3.226545  3.226698  3.221418
1     3.231642  3.226331  3.221449
2     3.231123  3.226454  3.226240
3     3.226484  3.226240  3.221571
4     3.226118  3.226331  3.221021
```

I tried to use pivot like this:

```
x.pivot(columns='site_num', values=6890011)
```

but it doesn't seem to allow me to skip the 'index' portion.

i've been trying to use set_index(), stack() and unstack() but i just can't get the result that I want. Using groupby() will force me to process the data further (sum, count etc) instead of just listing the values. How would you have done it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `item` index in your dataframe is a red-herring in the sense that the `item`s in the input have nothing to do with the `item`s in the desired output. The `item` values you would need to make pivot work look like this:

```
In [67]: x.reset_index(drop=True)
Out[67]: 
     6890011  site_num  item
0   3.226545         0     0
1   3.226698         1     0
2   3.221418         2     0
3   3.231642         0     1
4   3.226331         1     1
5   3.221449         2     1
6   3.231123         0     2
7   3.226454         1     2
8   3.226240         2     2
9   3.226484         0     3
10  3.226240         1     3
11  3.221571         2     3
12  3.226118         0     4
13  3.226331         1     4
14  3.221021         2     4
```

You can create this `item` column using `groupby/cumcount`:

```
x['item'] = x.groupby(['site_num']).cumcount()
```

---

Once you have the right values in the `item` column, the `pivot` call follows naturally:

```
In [63]: x['item'] = x.groupby(['site_num']).cumcount()

In [64]: x.pivot(columns='site_num', index='item')
Out[64]: 
           6890011                    
site_num         0         1         2
item                                  
0         3.226545  3.226698  3.221418
1         3.231642  3.226331  3.221449
2         3.231123  3.226454  3.226240
3         3.226484  3.226240  3.221571
4         3.226118  3.226331  3.221021
```

---

Another way to achieve this result is to extract a NumPy array from `x['6890011']` and use `reshape`:

```
In [78]: pd.DataFrame(x['6890011'].values.reshape(-1, 3))
Out[78]: 
          0         1         2
0  3.226545  3.226698  3.221418
1  3.231642  3.226331  3.221449
2  3.231123  3.226454  3.226240
3  3.226484  3.226240  3.221571
4  3.226118  3.226331  3.221021
```

This is very fast but far less robust since it ignores the actual `site_num`s and simply
assumes that the `site_num`s cycle through `0,1,2` and that `len(x['site_num'])` is a multiple of 3. The `groupby/cumcount/pivot` method will work even if `len(x['site_num'])` is not a multiple of 3 by adding NaNs as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another attempt (that is not necessarily pretty):

```
>>> grouped = x.groupby('site_num')['6890011']
>>> pd.DataFrame([grouped.get_group(group).values for group in grouped.groups]).T
          0         1         2
0  3.226545  3.226698  3.221418
1  3.231642  3.226331  3.221449
2  3.231123  3.226454  3.226240
3  3.226484  3.226240  3.221571
4  3.226118  3.226331  3.221021
```